# Configuring ElasticSearch relevance score to prefer a match on all words over a match with some words?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, with a search for "stack overflow" I want a document containing both "stack" and "overflow" to have a higher score than a document containing only one of those words.

Right now, I am seeing cases where a document that contains "stack" 0 times and "overflow" 50 times gets ranked above a document that contains "stack" 1 time and "overflow" 1 time.

A secondary concern is ranking documents higher that have the exact word as opposed to a word variant. For example, a document containing "stack" should be ranked higher than a document containing "stacking".

A third concern is ranking documents higher that have the words adjacent. For example a document "How to use stack overflow" should be ranked higher than a document "The stack of papers caused the inbox to overflow."

If you put those three concerns together, here is an example of the desired rank of results for "stack overflow":

[image: Example search results]

Is it possible to configure an index or a query to calculate score this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are trying to achieve multiple things in a single query. First you should try to understand how ES is returning you the results.

1. Document containing **overflow** 50 times gets ranked above a document that contains "stack" 1 time and "overflow" 1 time because ES score calculation is based on [tf/idf](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/scoring-theory.html#tfidf) based score calculation. And in this case obviously, **overflow** comes 50 times which is quite higher than other frequency combined for other 2 
   terms in another document.

Note:- You can disable this calculation as mentioned in the link.

> If you don’t care about how often a term appears in a field and all
>   you care about is that the term is present, then you can disable term
>   frequencies in the field mapping:

2. You are getting the results containing the term `stacking` due to [stemming](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stemming.html) and if you don't want document containing `stacking` shouldn't come in search results, than don't documents in stemmed form or do some post-processing after getting the results from ES and reduce their score, not sure if ES provide it out of the box.
3. The third thing which you want is a [phrase search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html).

Also use [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to understand, how ES calculates the score of the document with your query, It will help you to construct the right query according to your requirements.